# Set up SSRS on Windows 7

Tags: ssrs-2008

I Installed SSRS on my Win 7 Machine but I don't see it in my IIS website, and when i try to go to http://localhost/reportserver it asks for credentials which i put my admin account credentials and it doesn't work.

Thanks,
Marios

Answer (score 0):

SSRS 2008 does not create folders in IIS. It uses HTTP.sys to host the web sites itself.

Have you tried starting your browser using elevated (Administrator) permissions?